# Generate relationship data

Tags: java, python

I have a set of xml files representing rules manager rules. There are several elements that map to tables or table-attribute pairs.
I would like to discover all the elements that affect intersecting sets of tables or table-attributes.
I can work in java or possibly python, or command line Windows/Mac. Can someone suggests a tool or approach? Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use Jackson to deserialize XML to java class and write business logic around it here is the example: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: This is good - however I"ll repost another question as this has made it a bit clearer to me that using a language especially java is a bit more than I want to do right now since I just want to try various samples and the command line is looking like a better fit (starlet or Powershell). Sorry to seem idiotic but I can't see a checkmark to accept this answer even though I'm the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experiment with xmlStarlet
Try Saxon for cross file xpath queries
Both can work from the command line